# What is the proper way to offset a pointer?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm porting some gcc C code to msvc C, it has a lot of pointer offsetting done by simply adding an integer to the pointer like this:

```
memcpy(data+offset, uhus->elements[i], uhsize);
```

It seems like C in VS2013 won't allow for that though. I remember reading somewhere that adding an integer to a pointer in C offset it by i*sizeof(datatype of the pointer), wont matter for void* like in the line above but there might be some other types elsewhere and since the software is for flashing firmware, I'd rather avoid bricking my device while testing.

Currently I've replaced the additions like this:

```
static void* ptrOffset(void* ptr, int offset) {
    return (void*)(((int)ptr) + offset);
}
memcpy(ptrOffset(data, offset), uhus->elements[i], uhsize);
```

Should do the trick, no?

Comment: How is `data` declared?

Comment: oh data in this case is void*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want an auxiliary function for that, the proper definition would be:

```
void* ptrOffset(void* ptr, int offset) {
    return (char*)ptr + offset;
}
```

Doing pointer arithmetic on void pointers is technically not allowed. Also, casting a pointer to int will break on 64 bit platforms: you'll lose the top 32 bits of your pointer.

Comment: A macro or `inline` function may work better, depending on how often this is called.

Comment: I'd also add that if you are pointing to some random blob of data, `char*` is probably a better type than `void*` to be using anyway.  `void*` means "I don't know what I'm pointing at" -- but you do, don't you?

Comment: Meh, modern compilers are smart enough to inline functions without further hints.

Comment: `inline` also doesn't guarantee that a function will be inlined.  It has more to do with allowing a function to be defined in multiple translation units without causing any errors during linking than it has to do with forcing the compiler to inline.

Comment: its used a lot but the whole thing should take less than 1ms to execute regardless

Comment: There is some overhead with function calls.

Comment: @1000Bites: Not always.  Sometimes you have to restructure your program to get something inlined.  However, I don't see how this is relevant to the question.